# Video file with DRM removed

Tags: video, media, drm

Is there any way to check whether media files I download from the web were previously DRM-protected files with removed protection. There are some utilities like [DRM media converter software](http://www.yourtopsoft.com/software/aimersoft-drm-media-converter-for-windows-coupon-code-35-discount/), are these tools leaving any fingerprints making possible to determine using them analyzing the media?

Comment: Only if tool does not clean the media correctly. Eg. in MP4 it can simply remove all atoms related to protection and you have no chance to find if the asset was protected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the metadata. If the program that erased the DRM cleared the metadata, the file won't have a publisher, album etc.

However, if the program that removed the DRM fixed the metadata, the file would be identical to a file that never had DRM applied.

The link in the above post to "DRM media converter software" points to a dead site.